# When using an event in JQUERY, I can't get it to make changes like I was able to with JavaScript Pure. change () method

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom, onchange

I am a student, quite an amateur of javascript, at this moment I am introducing myself to Jquery, and I must pass some functions under this library, I cannot find a way to do this that I used to do so easily in pure JavaScript.
The function that I had created in javascript, allowed that if an input of type range was moved, an input number, was altered at the same time, and the number changed.

Javascript Code

```
sliderV.onchange = function (){
    inputV.value = sliderV.value;
}
```

Jquery try

```
$("#inputRange").change(function(){
    $("#inputRange").val() = $("#aSolicitar").val();
});
```

Comment: Question titles should describe the problem, otherwise they cannot be found by users with similar problems.

Comment: Not everything you do with jquery should be restricted to only using jquery methods. in this case you have access to `this`, which has a `value` property that you can directly access rather than needing $() and .val(). `this.value = $("#aSolicitar").val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving you an generic answer because I can't get your range input and number input selectors exactly.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=range]', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('input[type=number]').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

You can change your selector as your convenience.
E.g. **input[type=range]** to **#inputRange**

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=range]', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('input[type=number]').val( $(this).val() );
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>JQuery Range input change event</p>
<input type="range" id="inputRange" value="50" />
<br/>
<input type="number" id="inputNumber" value="50" />
```

Comment: Hi! You solved my problem and clarified my doubt, about how to face these situations when it is necessary to make comparison of values

Comment: Why event delegation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a function call to something. Try this instead.

```
$("#inputRange").change(function(){
    var aSolicitar = $("#aSolicitar").val();
    $(this).val(aSolicitar);
});
```